# How to change the hour:minutes:seconds format in keith-wood plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, countdown

How to change the **hour:minutes:seconds** format in [keith-wood plugin  jquery countdown plugin](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html)

Comment: Which plugin you are referring to?

Comment: No idea what this is about. Try to use all 5 allowed tags.

Comment: i want to change 0:0:12 format to 00:00:12.....

Comment: Is anybody have the answer...

Comment: i'm using keith-wood countdown timer plugin...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **layout** option in the plugin

```
$('#countbox').countdown({

layout:'<b>{d<}{dn}:{d>}'+ 
    '{hn}: {mn} : {sn} </b>'

});
```

please refer http://keith-wood.name/countdownRef.html

for two digit clock use **{hnn},{mnn},{snn}**

Answer (score 0):

So do you think?

```
$('#noDays').countdown({until: liftoffTime, format: 'HMS'});
```

**format    string  'dHMS'**:

The format for the countdown display. Use the following characters (in order) to indicate which periods you want to display: 'Y' for years, 'O' for months, 'W' for weeks, 'D' for days, 'H' for hours, 'M' for minutes, 'S' for seconds.